# iPhone transparent keyboard

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

How could I change the look and feel of standard UIKeyboard object. I want to create transparent keyboard for UITextField object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the keyboardAppearance property on your UITextField object to UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert:

```
myTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
```